# How do I use a Ruby gem on my Rails site?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, gemfile

I'm working on a Rails web site (https://github.com/jhsu802701/dvi) called Doppler Value Investing that uses my very first Ruby gem (dvi_scraper, source code at https://github.com/jhsu802701/dvi_scraper).  dvi_scraper downloads and processes financial statements from publicly traded companies, and dvi shows the results.  The results are saved in a Postgres database and in a *.csv file.

I added dvi_scraper to the Gemfile for my Rails app, and I used "bundle install" to install it.  However, the scripts and files from dvi_scraper DO NOT show up in the dvi directory where I'm working on my Rails site.  Instead, they're all at /home/(my username)/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/dvi_scraper-0.0.0 .  And the Dvi_scraper.dopeler command doesn't work in my dvi app.

What do I need to do to get the files from dvi_scraper to show up in my dvi app?  As you might guess, I don't really understand how RubyGems and Gemfile work even though I've used them.

Comment: do you check out running `bundle exec YOURBINARY`? do you use rvm or rbenv?

Comment: Your gems are downloading to the correct place.  Why do you need them in your Rails path?

Comment: Are you trying to have files in a proper place (from your gem) inside your rails app? (and if so, why?)

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior.  The gem files are automatically included (typically) when added via the Gemfile.

From the console

```
rails console
```

Try running

```
require_or_load 'dvi_scraper'
```

This should return true if the gem is properly installed